# Authentication error when accessing public SODA endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, socrata, soda

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to author a workflow and using the "Call HTTP Web Service" access to access the soda endpoint https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/7xgt-tyms.json?fac_id=1

The response I get is the following json object

> {"code":"authentication_required","error":true,"message":"Authentication
>   failed: Unsupported authorization type"}

but, as far as I can tell, this end point does not require authentication. I've also tried it with my own app token and received the same result. I was able to get this workflow to work using Microsoft's sample odata endpoint that they provide at http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')?$format=json&$select=ContactName,CompanyName

Comment: Do you know what kind of authorization it is using? Is there a way to disable authorization so it doesn't even try? If you pass invalid authentication details it'll reject your request, even if the dataset is public.

Comment: AFAIK, this SharePoint 2013 workflow (in the cloud) is not using any authentication. It is written using this example. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try our OData endpoint for that dataset? It might work better out of the box with Sharepoint Designer.

http://dev.socrata.com/odata/

Comment: That was a good idea, but I got the same response from the OAuth endpoint at https://health.data.ny.gov/OData.svc/vn5v-hh5r?$filter=fac_id%20eq%201

Comment: It still sounds like SharePoint is trying to send authentication even though it doesn't need to. I don't have a copy of SharePoint to test with, and I haven't been able to find any details on how to enable or disable authentication with SharePoint Web Service calls, but there's got to be a toggle in there somewhere you can flip.